# Working with files using Java

Tags: java, nosql

I have a query in regards to what is the best way of handling huge files in Java? 
Shall we use the no-sql database like Cassandra or try to use our existing Oracle database (to dump the content of the file).

My file can contain at most 1 or 2 fields. But mostly what I shall be able to do with the file content is just search an Id and return boolean.
File can contain records in tens of millions or as low as thousands.
Also this file can get refreshed on daily basis. Whenever refreshed I need to clear all previous values.

Any suggestions would be helpful!!

Regards,
Vicky

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements,

Oracle

1. Is good for indexing and fits your requirements if every day data is in tens of millions.
2. Index will be stored in memory and searches will be faster for this short data. If table is also short you can also request to keep table in memory and that will be even faster if any other column is also required.
3. You can drop table every day and import file again as new table. This should work.

Cassandra

1. Is also good for indexing. All your searches will also be faster (similar to oracle for such small data)
2. Cassandra is NoSQL database designed to provide scalability, high write throughput, availability for high volume data and queries.
3. Cassandra generally runs in clustered environments for above properties.

I would suggest to check your requirements, If you just to keep data in DB and wants to query once in a while or maybe 100 requests per sec then using Cassandra is like hitting a nail in wall with sledgehammer where small hammer or mallet is enough.